# Let autocompletion search also in related files

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When I use Vim to code in C/C++, I have a nice features: the autocomplete (`<CTRL>+N`) shows me names (variables, functions, classes...) that are defined both in the current document and in all of the imported documents.

Now, I am coding in Racket, and such feature is not present.

Is there a way to set it?

It would be more than enough to let Vim look just in the files in the same directory of the current one.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That C/C++ feature you're seeing is because `'complete'` contains the `i` value for included files, and Vim knows how to parse the `#include` statements. For another language like Racket, you have the following options:

1. Teach Vim how to parse included files; cp. `:help 'include'`.
2. Just let Vim look into the current directory, e.g. via `:let &l:dictionary = expand('%:p:h') . '/*'`.